# R: somewhat atypical full_join() with missings in key variable

Tags: r, dplyr, full-join

I have two tables `df1` and `df2` I want to full_join() using the "id" variable as a key.
Cases without `id` (=NA) should just be added as a row.

Does someone know, how to achieve this?

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA, NA),
                  t1 =  c(1, 2, 3, 4,  5,  6))

df1

df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA, 4),
                  t2 =  c(1, 2, 3, 4,  NA, 5)) 

df2

df1 %>% full_join(df2, by = "id")
```

Expected output:

```
id t1 t2
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  NA 5
NA 4  NA   # from df1
NA 5  NA   # from df1
NA 6  NA   # from df1
NA NA  4   # from df2
NA NA NA   # from df2
```

Comment: You mean, `df1 %>% full_join(df2, by = "id")`?

Comment: yes, sorry, I corrected it

Comment: `df1 %>% full_join(df2, by = "id", na_matches = "never")`

Answer (score 0):

The dplyr way is to use `na_matches = "never"`, as in [Seth's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77475047/r-somewhat-atypical-full-join-with-missings-in-key-variable/77479126#comment136584535_77475047). The equivalent way of doing this with base R is to use the `incomparables` parameter of `merge()`:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = "id", all = TRUE, incomparables = NA)
```

Output:

```
  id t1 t2
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
4  4 NA  5
5 NA  4 NA
6 NA  5 NA
7 NA  6 NA
8 NA NA  4
9 NA NA NA
```